# Hiding UIToolBar when calling camera (UIImagePicker)

Tags: iphone, camera, uitoolbar

I have created a UIToolBar using the IB.  In one view, I have called the camera and the camera controls are masked by the toolbar.

I have tried several methods to hide the toolbar - alpha=0, toolBarHidden, hidesBottomBarWhenPushed and thought how I could re-size the camera view to allow the camera controls to be used.  All with no luck.

I believe I must create a custom toolbar and then I can use the hide method.

My camera code is the standard:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
imagePicker.delegate = self;            
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Any code or final direction would be appreciated from this newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Try to shift the toolbar off the screen by changing the frame of it by providing y cordinate more than 480 for iphone.

Comment: I believe creating a custom toolbar in a view and then trying to hide the toolbar in a method does not work under any circumstances.  But, I would like any experts thoughts on the matter.  Because my next step would be to create a custom camera where the controls are not at the bottom of the screen.  This route seems difficult for a newbie...something like tapping the screen to take the picture and showing the re-take or use controls.

Comment: FYI.  I created a custom toolbar with 4 buttons in the toolbar.  But, I believe it is not possible to eliminate the toolbar in code contain within an IBAction id (sender) on the same view.  I am now thinking I need to create a separate h and m file to implement the camera without the toolbar.

Comment: toolbar.hidden = YES works only for the UINavigation toolbar....It does not work for the UIToolbar.

Experts please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to "hide" the toolbar. It removes the standard "take picture ,etc" buttons and replaces it with a black bar with the same width/height of the default overlay.

```
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

[iOS reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/showsCameraControls)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion....but....The above code does not hide the toolbar but eliminates the camera controls.  I only want to eliminate the toolbar that I have created and keep the camera controls.  If I nix the standard controls then I need to write alternate code such as tap the screen or custom buttons for taking the picture, retake or save to the photo album.